# C - Segmentation fault for select values of fprintf

Tags: c

I have a piece of code that calculates coordinates from a user defined size of grid, and prints them to a text file. However when I run the program I get a segmentation fault but only for values of 5 or 7 for the grid, all other values work as intended.

The code is as follows

```
// Writing OUTPUT 1 to file
// Creating & opening file
FILE *f1 = fopen("coords_output.txt", "w");
if(f1 == NULL)
{
    printf("Error in opening file\n");
    exit(0);
}
// Writing to file
for(i=0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j < arrayLength; j++)
    {
        fprintf(f1, "\n%d,%d %d", i, j, coordArray[i][j]);
    }
}   
// Close file
fclose(f1);here
```

If the whole section under //writing to file is removed the program works, and no matter what I place there the program will fail.

I don't have a great understanding of c, especially when it comes to areas like this, however I have spent a lot of time on trying to fix this problem and cannot seem to come to an answer.

EDIT:
coordArray is defined as

```
coordArray = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int *));
for(i=0; i <= arrayLength; i++) 
{
    coordArray[i] = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int));
}
```

arrayLength is taken from user input

```
validInput = validInput && sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &arrayLength);
```

Comment: How is `coordArray` declared?

Comment: We need more code, also, have you tried the debugger?

Comment: at least `coordArray` and `arrayLength`

Comment: added coordArray to post, @Isaiah I have no experience with the debugger or how to use it

Comment: Are you checking the return value from `malloc()` to make sure it's not null?  What OS?

Comment: You should learn how to, if you use an ide, then you should be able to set breakpoints exactly where you need to and able to print out variables

Comment: In the for loop in which you initialize `coordArray`, you have an off-by-one error because the condition to terminate the loop is `i <= arrayLength`, meaning that the loop will continue, even when i = arrayLength.  Since c arrays are 0-based, that it will go beyond the length of the array.

Comment: See this; its buried in the entries, but really good resource: [C FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/C-faq/faq/)

Comment: @JohnZwinck Just added a check for malloc and its not returning null. OS is windows

Comment: See arthur's comment. Also, you should use %u as thats unsigned int and we cant allocate negative space.

Comment: @ArthurLaks I have tried changing this already and the result is still the same. I'm confused as to why the code executes perfectly for any arrayLength (odd numbers only) except for 5 and 7.

Comment: Check the article I linked -- look for array of pointers or something like that. Try here: [dynamically allocating array of arrays](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

Comment: the posted code is executing beyond the end of the array, resulting in undefined behaviour, which  leads to corruption of the stack, corruption of the heap, and (in the 5,7 cases) results in a seg fault event.

Comment: Also, CoordArray has not been declared as a pointer according to your code.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't work (modified from the code you provided):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arrayLength = 5;
    int i,j;
    int **coordArray;
    coordArray = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i <= arrayLength; i++)
    {
        coordArray[i] = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < arrayLength; j++)
        {
            printf("\n%d,%d %d", i, j, coordArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work because the first `for` loop is accessing 1 beyond the end of the array. Even though it may appear to work, the code is broken regardless of the value of `arrayLength`. The reason it may work for some values is due to how segmentation faults occur, there are lots of resources on the Internet about when and why they occur, here's a [random one](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/segfaults.html) which seems to explain it well.

This code works (notice the change from `<=` to `<` in the first `for` loop):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arrayLength = 5;
    int i,j;
    int **coordArray;
    coordArray = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int *));
    for(i=0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        coordArray[i] = malloc(arrayLength * sizeof(int));
    }
    for(i=0; i < arrayLength; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < arrayLength; j++)
        {
            printf("\n%d,%d %d", i, j, coordArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It can be difficult to find bugs like this without using a debugger or an analysis tool like Valgrind. I'd strongly recommend that you take the time to learn how to use tools like that so that you can find the source of these bugs in the future.